# How to know if a Git tag has been moved?

Tags: git, git-tag

I used `git tag --force` to move a tag, and now I want to know where was the tag before I move it.

I didn't find anything in the manual pages nor on the website [Pro Git § 2.6 Git Basics - Tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Nobody seems to have posted this question before.

Comment: Is this a tag object, or a lightweight tag? If the former, the information might be stored in the reflog; otherwise, I don't think Git keeps any information about what a tag name *used* to refer to.

Comment: @chepner: annotated tags (tag objects) live in the repository and persist as long as there's a reference.  (And a bit longer if the gc is not immediate...)  The lone reference usually comes from a corresponding `refs/tags/` name-space entry, which is where a lightweight tag is stored.  Lightweight tags simply point directly to a commit, rather than to an annotated tag object.  In all cases there is a reflog only if you've made one, as tags by default don't get them made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to have kept tabs (tags?) on the tag before-hand.

As noted in comments, there are two kinds of tags: "annotated" and "lightweight".

In both cases, for a tag named *`T`*, git creates a reference named `refs/tags/T`.  For a lightweight tag, this name points directly to some commit.  For an annotated tag, git first creates an "annotated tag" object in the repository (this is stored in the same way as a commit, tree, or blob), and then has the reference name—which would otherwise just be a "lightweight tag"—point to the annotated tag object.  The annotated tag object then points to the next link in the chain, normally a commit object.

When updating a reference, git checks the `logs` directory (normally `.git/logs`) to see if there's a file available corresponding to the ref-name.  If you peek into `.git/logs` you'll see a file named `HEAD` and a directory named `refs`.  Underneath `refs`, there's a directory named `heads`, and under `refs/heads` there is a file for each branch.  The `refs/heads/master` file contains the reflog for branch `master`, for instance.

By default, there is no `.git/logs/refs/tags` directory, hence there's no file for a tag and hence there's no reflog for tag updates.  This is because tags are not *intended* to move.  They're supposed to be permanent; that's the main property that's different between a tag-name and a branch-name: branch-tips move, tags don't.

However, if you intend to move a tag, and then want to know where it used to be, you *can* create `.git/logs/refs/tags` and then make a file in there containing the tag-name.  Once you have done that, tag updates will write a reflog entry.  Obviously this only helps if you plan this in advance.

There is one other direct way to recover "where a tag used to point": find an old record of the tag's SHA-1 value.  That's what a reflog would do, but if you don't have one, maybe you have a clone of the repository, and maybe that clone has the old tag.  Or you might get lucky and have a window where the SHA-1 is still shown in the scrollback, for instance.

---

If the tag was an annotated tag, you can search the repository for annotated tag objects that no longer have a reference, using `git fsck`.  This will generally produce a lot of output.  "Dangling blobs" are quite normal in an active repository, they occur when you `git add` something and then `git add` a different version before committing.
"Dangling commits" occur when commits get abandoned and their reflog entries expire.  The thing to look for here is a "dangling tag":

```
dangling tag 20e14672ee2253d38c1001179d8f17688d47059c
```

This will be the SHA-1 of the annotated tag object; you can attach a new reference (such as a new lightweight tag, or re-force the old one or whatever) to make sure it won't get `git gc`-ed and removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clears a lot of things.
Except that I had to add a file called as my tag under `.git/logs/refs/tags` not `.git/logs/tags`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very detailed, but there's a much easier way to tell git to include tags in the reflog:

`git config --global core.logallrefupdates always`

After setting this option, git will start keeping reflogs for all tags by default.